# Add footer.php to Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, functions, child-theme, code, footer

So I am using the theme of 'Mesmerize'

I have created a child theme but want to change some of the footer php within the child them so when there is a theme update the changes done reverse.

This is my **Functions.php** in my child theme \wp-content\themes\mesmerize-child

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array(  ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );
```

And below is the code which I need to change but within the child theme. I am needing to change the 'Built with Wordpress' text which I have been able to do just not using the child theme This is the **templates-functions.php** located within **\wp-content\themes\mesmerize\inc**

```
 //FOOTER FUNCTIONS

function mesmerize_get_footer_content($footer = null)
{
    $template = apply_filters('mesmerize_footer', null);

    if ( ! $template) {
        $template = $footer;
    }

    get_template_part('template-parts/footer/footer', $template);

}

function mesmerize_get_footer_copyright()
{
    $copyrightText = __('**Built using WordPress** and the <a target="_blank" href="%1$s" class="mesmerize-theme-link">Mesmerize Theme</a>', 'mesmerize');

    $copyrightText = sprintf($copyrightText, 'http://extendthemes.com/mesmerize');

    $copyright = '<p class="copyright">&copy;&nbsp;' . "&nbsp;" . date_i18n(__('Y', 'mesmerize')) . '&nbsp;' . esc_html(get_bloginfo('name')) . '.&nbsp;' . wp_kses_post($copyrightText) . '</p>';

    return apply_filters('mesmerize_get_footer_copyright', $copyright);
}
```

I have tried adding **templates-functions.php** to **\wp-content\themes\mesmerize-child\inc** with the changes but this did not work. I have looked through the code but can't seem to change this to get it to call the file from the child theme.

Also just for more information here is the footer.php file in the parent themes files.

```
        <?php mesmerize_get_footer_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you need any more info and any help will be appreciated with what I need to be doing here

Thanks

UPDATE - I HAVE TRIED THE BELOW from it being suggested in comments. I am posting this code of what I have tried so I can get some help with this.

```
    function change_copyrightText( $copyrightText ){
$copyrightText = __('Built using TEST and the <a target="_blank" href="%1$s" class="mesmerize-theme-link">TEST Theme</a>', 'mesmerize');

    return $copyrightText;
}

add_filter('change_copyrightText', 'change_copyrightText', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Any ideas anyone? :)

Comment: You can use the filter to modify the footer,  if you notice in the copyright function it has a filter called `mesmerize_get_footer_copyright` you can use that to Modify just the copyright text

Comment: Hi, I have been able to change the copyright text in the parent theme... but I am wanting to be able to leave the parent theme be as it will change when a theme update is applied. I have tried copying the file where I made the changes to the child theme location but this does not work. So I need a way to make the changes in the child theme rather than the parent theme if that makes sense?

Comment: I can see the filter but how would I use this to make the changes I need to do from the child theme? :)

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/285721/118765 Here is my answers that explains how to use filters, you would use it in your child themes `functions.php`

Comment: Let me know if you need further explanation,  I'll post it as an answer then

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I sort of understand what we are trying to do here but I cane execute this. I will post above what I have tried in my question :) Some help would be great if you can. I'm still getting to grips with PHP myself. Sorry if I'm being a bit dumb here ahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong argument for the filter.  The first argument of the `add_filter` is the filter you are hooking up to. In your case it's the `mesmerize_get_footer_copyright`. The second argument is the Call back function that would run the filter is called.
So change your `add_filter` to this

`add_filter('mesmerize_get_footer_copyright', 'change_copyrightText', 10,1) ;`

Comment: Ahh I see now! So the first filter is what I am wanting to change the details of... the second filter is calling back to the function created earlier in the code! I've got it now! That' great and its working perfectly now! Really good explanation and its helped me understand the code way more clearly now!